# Should input power be greater than output power in a buck converter?

Tags: power-supply, buck, switching-regulator

For example,

in order to provide for 10W (5V*2A), the input must be greater than 10W?

I asked this because in datasheets, only input voltage is mentioned. There is no mention of the input current. I assumed, as the voltage decreases, current increases. Of course, the power will be the same. 12V*1A = 12W. 6V*2A = 12W. Else, I am wrong again.

Comment: Yes it should be larger, but what datasheet are you talking about?

Comment: Onlly with certainty in this universe. In others, MAYBE not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's no such thing as a converter with 100% or better efficiency.  A reasonable  buck converter will have an efficiency between maybe 70% and 92-93%

So input power will be the output power divided by the efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer is assuming that everyone knows and obeys(1) the Laws of Physics, and that the input current at the input voltage **must** provide enough input power to cover the output power + losses.

(1) unlike speeding/parking laws, or theft/murder laws, you don't get to choose whether to obey the Laws of Physics or not!

Answer (score 0):

There will be graphs in the datasheet. One will give efficiency at different loads. Find the worst case efficiency for your range of loads.

[image]

Then divide the maximum output power you desire by that efficiency percentage. That is the minimum input power you need to provide. Also add a little more on top. A bit of de-rating never hurt anyone.